# Can someone please explain use of Grunt(WRT to Angular JS) with example?

Tags: angularjs

I am studying angular js and in our project they are using Grunt to setup the angular js application, as i can directly include angular.js in my html file and run it in a browser so where Grunt is coming into picture?

Answer (score 1):

Grunt is a task runner. It is used to run tasks to prepare your application for the wide world.

For example you might use Grunt to minify your javascript files or concatenate them.
So Grunt prepares your application, but once it's prepared - it is out of the picture when you deploy your application.